# English Legal Case Shorthand: e.g. 13 & 14 Charles II c. 33

Tags: history, abbreviations, legalese

I've been reading scholarship that details English court cases, and the cases in those reports are often referred to in quick shorthand, e.g.:

```
13 & 14 Charles II c. 33
4 William & Mary c. 4
```

Does anyone know the name or rules for this kind of shorthand? Also, does anyone know of a comprehensive database of these laws?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. It is partly about legal shorthand, surely best asked on a website dealing with legal styles, and partly a request for resources.

Comment: These are citations of laws, not cases: the first numbers are regnal years, followed by the name of the sovereign; 'c.' designates the 'chapter', the number of the act in sequence of (I think) Royal Assent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two examples that you give aren't cases. They are English Acts of Parliament.

The first one (13 & 14 Charles II c. 33) is entitled 'An Act for preventing the frequent Abuses in printing seditious, treasonable, and unlicensed Books and Pamphlets, and for regulating of Printing and Printing Presses'. It was passed into law in the 13th/14th year of the reign of Charles II, and has the 'chapter' number  33 assigned to it (ie it is the 33rd Act passed in that year).
The second one (4 William & Mary c. 4) was passed into law in the 4th year of the reign of William and Mary, and has the 'chapter' number 4 assigned to it (ie it is the 4th Act passed in that year).

This sort of citation is what was used for 'early statutes'. Since just before 1900 most UK Acts of Parliament have a 'short title', by which they are commonly known and are usually cited (thanks to the Short Titles Act 1896 and the Statute Law Revision Act 1948, which authorised some short titles for Acts passed before 1896). So now, instead of saying '52 Elizabeth II c. 12' (ie the 12th Act passed by Parliament in the 52nd year of the reign of Elizabeth II), you'd say 'the Finance Act 2004'. 
If you want a list of how Acts are cited (or which Acts are still current in UK law) see the [Chronological Table of the Statutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronological_Table_of_the_Statutes)

Comment: Does the chapter go by order of passage or order of Assent?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I would imagine it's in order of passage (ie the last date that Parliament dealt with it). So if the Act doesn't come into force for 6 months after it has been finalised, it will have a lower chapter number than than an Act that is rushed through after it and comes into force immediately. For the very old Acts, though, it's unlikely that it will make any real difference, as there are relatively few of those Acts still left on the statute book.

Comment: (Though actually, 'passage' and 'Royal Assent' are virtually the same thing, in that an Act will not be 'passed' until it has received Assent.)